# Add multiple consecutive whitespaces in a string replace operation

Tags: whitespace, openrefine

g.e. I would like to prepend all occurrences of the string "foo" with three spaces:

```
value.replace(/(foo)/, "   " + "$1")
value.replace(/(foo)/, "   $1")
value.replace(/(foo)/, " " + " " + " $1")
```

all return

```
 foo
```

instead of

```
   foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the follow GREL expression `value.replace('foo', ' foo')` ?